# WP Meta Query - mixed AND / OR query doesn't work

Tags: mysql, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query

I am absolutely boggled by this one.

I am creating a search function for a property site - simple enough. Simple queries such as `max_price`, `max_beds`, `rent_or_buy` work ok. But I am trying to create a keyword match search that can query `postcode`, `project_id` and `suburb` my query comes up empty.

My `meta_query` argument of `WP_Query` looks like this;

```
(
    [relation] => AND
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key] => for_buy_or_rent
            [value] => buy
            [compare] => =
            [type] => CHAR
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [relation] => OR
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => project_id
                    [value] => 3066
                    [compare] => LIKE
                    [type] => NUMERIC
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [key] => postcode
                    [value] => 3066
                    [compare] => LIKE
                    [type] => NUMERIC
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [key] => suburb
                    [value] => 3066
                    [compare] => LIKE
                    [type] => CHAR
                )
        )
)
```

note - I use a switch case to build it on the fly.

Running $projects->request outputs the following SQL;

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.id 
FROM   wp_posts 
       INNER JOIN wp_postmeta 
               ON ( wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
       INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 
               ON ( wp_posts.id = mt1.post_id ) 
WHERE  1 = 1 
       AND (( ( wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%3066%' ) 
               OR ( wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%3066%' ) 
               OR ( wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%3066%' ) )) 
       AND ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'for_buy_or_rent' 
               AND Cast(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'buy' ) 
             AND ( ( mt1.meta_key = 'project_id' 
                     AND Cast(mt1.meta_value AS signed) LIKE '%3066%' ) 
                    OR ( mt1.meta_key = 'postcode' 
                         AND Cast(mt1.meta_value AS signed) LIKE '%3066%' ) 
                    OR ( mt1.meta_key = 'suburb' 
                         AND Cast(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%3066%' ) ) ) 
       AND wp_posts.post_type = 'project' 
       AND ( wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
              OR wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' 
              OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future' 
              OR wp_posts.post_status = 'draft' 
              OR wp_posts.post_status = 'pending' 
              OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private' ) 
GROUP  BY wp_posts.id 
ORDER  BY wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%3066%' DESC, 
          wp_posts.post_date DESC 
LIMIT  0, 24
```

If I get rid of the sub-query `OR`, it works. If I try to use one of the sub queries on the top level `AND` query, it doesn't match. Check a screenshot of my database to ensure the match is there:

[image: they are in there!]

Comment: What is the issue here ? This meta query will display results when `for_buy_or_rent` is `buy` **AND** `postcode` is `3066` ? What is your desired result ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. `postcode` doesn't even work by itself though.

Comment: Then change it to OR `[relation] => AND` that is on the beginning!

Comment: if you're trying to get a postcode exact match, `=` is much faster than `LIKE`

Answer (score 0):

```
if($search->keyword){
    $project_args['s'] = $search->keyword;
}
```

That was the culprit. FML!

Everything else was correct.